# Facebook OpenGraph Action not being approved

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to submit for my application a Facebook open graph action of Read. But when i submit it i got the following response.

> We are unable to test this action according to the usage instructions
>   you provided. Please provide thorough reproduction instructions and
>   link(s) to a specific URL where we can trigger the action. You should
>   also test your action to ensure you can successfully publish actions
>   back to the timeline of the test user named Auth Dialog Preview User.
>   Once you have made these changes, re-submit your action.

I can understand the first part, but I don't understand the following parts.

> You should also test your action to ensure you can successfully
>   publish actions back to the timeline of the test user named Auth
>   Dialog Preview User. Once you have made these changes, re-submit your
>   action.

What does this means and how can I fix them? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It means you have to use the automatically created test user for your app called 'Auth Dialog Preview User' and post some of the actions from that user's account.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ explains how test users work in general, you can log in as them via the app settings interface